# How can I Login my iPhone application using Twitter Account?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing a iPhone application in which user has to login through it's Twitter Account.

Just like this web site http://sawthem.com

This is just like login using OpenID.

Please provide me some help.

Comment: @middaparka I cannot find answer so i cannot marked them as answer. Where as i am finding answer i marked them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Come on Dude, Google is never more than 3 clicks away :)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

All in there